# "eval is evil", but do I have an option?

Tags: javascript, eval

I've came up with some custom localization solution for a project I'm working on. The idea is that my HTML can contain this:

```
<h2 data-l10n="HELLO" data-l10n-params="['Visitor', new Date()]"></h2>
```

When the page is initiated a javascript function like this runs:

```
localizeAll: function(sel) {
    var selector = sel || document,
        $o = $(selector);

    $o.find('[data-l10n]').each(
    function() {
        var $t = $(this),
            val = $t.attr('data-l10n'),
            params = $t.attr('data-l10n-params'),
            po = null;

        if (typeof params !== 'undefined') {
            po = eval(params);
            log(params, po);
        }

        var res = doLocalize(val, po);

        if (res[0] !== '<') {
            $t.text(res);
        } else {
            $t.text(val);
        }
    });

}
```

So basically we search for any elements that have a `data-l10n`-attribute and call `doLocalize()` for each of those objects. Additionally, the element can have a `data-l10n-params`-attribute, which is just a string literal that can be parsed to an array. This string is evaluated (`params` string becomes `po` array) and `po` is supplied to `doLocalize()` as the optional second parameter.

Hence, the output in Firebug (from `log(params, po);` statement) is:

```
['Vistor', new Date()] ["Vistor", Date {Thu Nov 17 2011 10:10:31 GMT+0100 (CET)}]
```

So yes, I'm using eval. And yes, I know that "eval is evil". But occasionally, I need to pass a parameter to `doLocalize()`.

How could this be done without eval?

Comment: Very interesting solution. I'm wondering why you've done it like this. This way, the html kind of tells the JS what to do, instead of the JS completing the html. I feel the two should be more separated, which would also make your HTML valid (now it's not). So, is there a special reason for this approach?

Comment: @kasimir: If you mean the `data-` attributes then they are actually valid in HTML5.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: thanks for pointing that out, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are effectively embedding JavaScript in HTML (which is against the [*unobtrusive JavaScript*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) principle).

In your place I would add an extra `l18n-params.js` file with the following contents:

```
var dataL10Nparams = {
    HELLO = ['Visitor', new Date()]
}
```

Now instead of reading the params from HTML attribute and evaluating just call:

```
dataL10Nparams['HELLO']
```

Comment: Can't think of any drawbacks using your idea. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you only provide parameterized values in your HTML attribute, consider using [JSON.parse()](http://www.json.org/js.html) instead of evaluation.

Comment: JSON.parse() was my first option, but it wouldn't handle javascript inside the parameters, so things like `'{"key" : "value", "now" : new Date()}'` couldn't be parsed.